# How to insert dataframe with auto-increment in sql alchemy /sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have this code to insert dataframe into DB (SQLite) :

```
 l1 = df.to_dict(orient='record')
 meta = schema.MetaData(bind=db,reflect=True)
 t= Table(t1, meta, autoload=True)
 Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
 session = Session()
 db.execute(t.insert(), l1)
 session.commit()
 session.close()
```

It fails because the unique id of the table 'is not unique' (df comes from the db and fields have been modified).

in df, there is one unique id called id, which needs to be incremented.
However, how to specify the unique_id and how to make it increment automatically through sql alchemy?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found (if it helps anybody in same situation):

Just add this code, after creating the list, it would remove the id.

```
del l1['id']
```